# dict.setdefault() is used when value already exists

Tags: python, dictionary, setdefault

I'm trying to add new keys to the existing dictionary, setting as default value, the value of the previous key.

```
def check_data(end, start, profile):
    print(profile)

    for day in range((end-start).days+1):
        profile.setdefault(start+datetime.timedelta(day),
           {'expediture':0, 'top-up':0,
           'budget':profile[start+datetime.timedelta(day-1)]['budget'] })

start  = datetime.date(2019,2,1)
end    = datetime.date(2019,2,17)
check_data(end, start, month_data)
```

output from `print(profile)`:

```
    {datetime.date(2019, 2, 1): {'expediture': 0, 'top-up': 0, 'budget': 100.0}}

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-4-e44462627692> in <module>
    ----> 1 check_data(end, start, month_data)

    <ipython-input-2-90b936150b04> in check_data(end, start, profile)
         20         profile.setdefault(start+datetime.timedelta(day),
         21                                     {'expediture':0, 'top-up':0,
    ---> 22
       'budget':profile[start+datetime.timedelta(day-1)]['budget'] })
        23
        24 def add_money(profile, topup, date=datetime.date.today()):

       KeyError: datetime.date(2019, 1, 31)
```

I don't understand why `setdefault()` tries to set default value to
`datetime.date(2019, 2, 1)` if this value already exists.

I could fix this problem with `if` but I'd like to understand how `setdefault` works and maybe there is alternative solution for this problem.

Comment: The second argument to `setdefault` is evaluated before `setdefault` is actually run.

Comment: ALL parameters to a function are completely evaluated before the function is called - whether or not that function is actually going to make use of a particular parameter.  So in this case, you're creating the expenditure/top-up/budget dict unconditionally, even on the first day in which case the budget calculation fails due to lack of a previous day.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider how you would write this code *without* `setdefault` (and some minor refactoring for readability):

```
def check_data(end, start, profile):
    print(profile)

    for day in range((end-start).days+1):
        yesterday = start + datetime.timedelta(day - 1)
        today = start + datetime.timedelta(day)
        profile[today] = {
            'expenditure': 0,
            'top-up': 0,
            'budget': profile[yesterday]['budget']
        }

start  = datetime.date(2019,2,1)
end    = datetime.date(2019,2,17)
check_data(end, start, month_data)
```

On the first iteration of the loop, you need the value of `profile[datetime(2019,1,31)]` in order to set the value of `profile[datetime(2019,2,1)]`, but that value was never set.

The only use for `setdefault` here would be with the key `yesterday`, assuming you could start with some generic profile. For simplicity, I'll assume that `budget` is also an integer.

```
def check_data(end, start, profile):
    print(profile)

    for day in range((end-start).days+1):
        yesterday = start + datetime.timedelta(day - 1)
        today = start + datetime.timedelta(day)
        profile[today] = {
            'expenditure': 0,
            'top-up': 0,
            'budget': profile.setdefault(yesterday, {'budget': 0})['budget']
        }
```

Now, if `profile[yesterday]` doesn't already exist, `setdefault` will execute the equivalent of `profile[yesterday] = {'budget': 0}` before returning that value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have to process it in my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the error. A `KeyError` means you tried to look up a key in a dictionary but that key does not exist. In this case it looks like `profile[start+datetime.timedelta(day-1)]` is giving you the `KeyError` and is not related to the `setdefault` method call.